# mybatis multiple one-to-many relations duplicate entities

Tags: mybatis

I have three tables: `grandparent`, `parent` and `child`. The model is really simple: a grandparent has many parents and a parent has many children. And, I want to retrieve an aggregate of them in one `grandparent` object.

Here is my DDL of these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE grandparent (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE parent (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    grandparent_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    parent_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And, here is my MyBatis mapper file:

```
<mapper namespace="me.predatorray.mybatis.GrandparentMapper">
    <!-- grandparent -->
    <resultMap id="grandparentResultMap" type="me.predatorray.mybatis.Grandparent">
        <constructor>
            <idArg column="grandparent.id" javaType="long" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
            <arg column="grandparent.name" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        </constructor>
        <collection property="parents" column="parent.id" notNullColumn="parent.id"
                    javaType="java.util.ArrayList" ofType="me.predatorray.mybatis.Parent">
            <constructor>
                <idArg column="parent.id" javaType="long" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
                <arg column="parent.name" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
            </constructor>
            <collection property="children" column="child.id" notNullColumn="child.id"
                        javaType="java.util.ArrayList" ofType="me.predatorray.mybatis.Child">
                <constructor>
                    <idArg column="child.id" javaType="long" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
                    <arg column="child.name" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
                </constructor>
            </collection>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findGrandparentById" parameterType="long" resultMap="grandparentResultMap">
        SELECT * FROM grandparent
        LEFT JOIN parent ON grandparent.id = parent.grandparent_id
        LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
        WHERE grandparent.id = #{id, jdbcType=BIGINT};
    </select>
</mapper>
```

And, here is my entity classes:

```
public class Grandparent {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<Parent> parents;

    public Grandparent(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    }

    public void setParents(Collection<Parent> parents) {
        this.parents = parents;
    }

    ...getters
}

public class Parent {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<Child> children;

    public Parent(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Child>();
    }

    public void setChildren(Collection<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    ...getters
}

public class Child {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Child(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    ...getters
}
```

But, it seems that there is something wrong with my mapper. The grandparent object returned is not what i expect. There are duplicate parents in the grandparent. For example, given the case below,

```
INSERT INTO grandparent (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Daisy');

    INSERT INTO parent (id, name, grandparent_id) VALUES (2, 'Elizabeth', 3);
        INSERT INTO child (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (1, 'Frieda', 2);

    INSERT INTO parent (id, name, grandparent_id) VALUES (3, 'Grace', 3);
        INSERT INTO child (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (2, 'Helen', 3);
        INSERT INTO child (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (3, 'Ivy', 3);

    INSERT INTO parent (id, name, grandparent_id) VALUES (4, 'Jack', 3);
```

`findGrandparentById(3)` will return a grandparent like

```
Daisy (Grandparent)
  Elizabeth (Parent)
    Frieda (Child)
  Grace (Parent)
    Helen (Child)
  Grace (Parent)
    (C)Ivy (Child)
  Jack (Parent)
```

"Grace" who has two children duplicate twice in "Daisy". So, what's the problem?

### **EDIT**

After giving all columns a name (for example, grandparent.id AS gid, parent.id AS pid and so on), the problem is solved. I'm just wondering that maybe it is a bug of mybatis?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query. Try running it in an SQL client - it will return separate rows for Ivy and Helen. MyBatis is faithfully reflecting this.

I suspect that the result you want is unlikely to be retrieved by a simple query. Either you need to read the parent and child tables on demand, or possibly read the complete model into memory and work from there.

And slightly OT: Do you really need three tables? The model looks like a single table with an optional parentId field pointing to the immediate parent.